# How to add a custom resolution in Windows 10?

Tags: resolution, intel-graphics, windows-11, refresh-rate

I am using Windows 10 on a desktop computer and have an old AOC monitor. The problem is: It does not support ANY resolution given by the system, I tried changing refresh rate, screen resolution, etc. Some it says "Input Not Support", some it doesn't comes full screen if it supports. My guess is: it might support 1920x1080 59.995 Hz, but I only have option of 59.940 Hz in 1920x1080. I want to add a custom resolution, I tried Intel R Graphics Command Center, I can add a custom resolution, but not in decimal. For example when I type "59.995" it comes as "59995", I can't add decimal, and if I only try "59" it says already exist. So my question is: **How can I add a custom resolution with decimal in Refresh Rate?**

Comment: An application can allow or disallow any value in a text box, if the text box only allows while numbers, there isn’t anything you can do about that.

Comment: Yes it is... @Ramhound. So is there any other app(s) that allow(s) it?